# Jquery - Get the highest height out of three different divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a pinterest based grid system, everything's all fine and dandy and working except for one thing. The problem being because i'm using absolute positioning the container that wraps them all has to be set as actual pixels, so i came up with this code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.newsPageMain').css({height:(($('#newsEntry:nth-child(1)').height()) + ($('#newsEntry:nth-child(4)').height()) + ($('#newsEntry:nth-child(7)').height()) + 141)}); // ID 9
});
```

It works to a degree but the problem is, if another row is longer, the longest one is cropped off, so essentially i want to be able to work out the highest of nth-chlds 1,2,3 then 4,5,6 then 7,8,9 so i can add the highest together so the container will wrap correctly

I hope this makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

~Matt

Comment: This doesn't look like the right way to do this. Are the children of #newsEntry all the same size? You might want to look at: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Everything works a treat so far, there's no other problems, i'm working in wordpress so i'm having to use nth-child for each article of which the container is #newsEntry, i know there's masonry but i'm building this by hand for a reason

Comment: lol, just noticed your name is Matthew. This question needs more info for us to help. It they are all the same size why not just float left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get the tallest element from every group of 3 elements in the collection:

```
var $els = $('#newsEntry div'),
    height = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < $els.length; i += 3) {
    height += Math.max.apply(null, $divs.slice(i, i+3).map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
}
```

If you want to get the height including the padding and margin, you'd use [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/).

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjt46/10/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hackish but what about using .each to get the size of each container and set them all to the highest value?

```
   var maxHeight = 0;
   $('div.mycontainerclass').each(function (index, item) {
        //console.log($(this).height());
        maxHeight = ($(this).height() > maxHeight) ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
    });
    //console.log(maxHeight);
    //set heights etc...
```